# Copy contents of remote server folder to current server?

Tags: ftp, file-copy

I've been searching and I cannot find an answer on any of these sites that will work. I want to copy all of the contents of [this folder](ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/qfits/) to my server. Which Linux command should I use to do that? I don't want to manually run through all of the objects in that folder, one at a time per se. I've seen everything from scp to rsync, but can't get either to work.

Thanks,

Comment: Is sshd installed on the remove pc?

Comment: @Johan It's not my server I'm trying to copy the files from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use something like

```
cd directory-where-you-want-to-put-the-files
wget -r ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/qfits/
```

Comment: @PauloMaia "Do not forget…” or “Don't forget…”

Answer (score 2):

FTP?

```
#!/bin/sh
# ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/qfits/
HOST='ftp.eso.org'
USER='anonymous'
PASSWD='<your.email.address>'

ftp -n $HOST <<EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
prompt off
cd /pub/qfits
ls
mget *
quit
EOF
exit 0
```